# The best statistical test for dependent “different” sets?

Tags: anova, nonparametric, independence

I have to do my graduation project and I am facing this question regarding a statistical test.

This is my question:

Assume that I have to classify one image by a Neural Network 5 times (5 iterations) and each time it gives me these results:

```
Iteration 1 : class1: 0.0, class2: 0.5, class3: 0.5, class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.
Iteration 2 : class1: 1.0, class2: 0.0, class3: 0.0, class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.
Iteration 3 : class1: 0.5, class2: 0.5, class3: 0.0, class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.
Iteration 4 : class1: 0.0, class2: 1.0, class3: 0.0, class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.
Iteration 5 : class1: 0.0, class2: 0.0, class3: 1.0, class4: 0.0 >> The total is ONE.
```

I need to do a statistical test to know which CLASS is significantly different from the other classes.

My four sets will be:

1. class1 values from all iterations = (0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0)
2. class2 values from all iterations = (0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0)
3. class3 values from all iterations = (0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
4. class4 values from all iterations = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

I don't care about the internal differences or the time. All I need is that at the end of the last iteration, I can determine which class is different than the others.

I thought to use "One-way ANOVA" then "Tukey's test" exactly like here: http://cleverowl.uk/2015/07/01/using-one-way-anova-and-tukeys-test-to-compare-data-sets/

But the problem is that my data is kind of dependent.You can see that each iteration is added up to 1.

For example, in iteration#1, 0.0 + 0.5 + 0.5 = 1. In iteration#2, 1.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 = 1 and so on.

So, what is the best statistical test I can use in my situation?

Thank you